# Can I set an html text field value to a variable, so it saves the previously entered content?

Tags: php, html

`<?php $content = $_POST['content']?>`
`<p>Page title: <input type='text' name='title' value="<?php $content ?>"/></p>`

I would like to know if something like this is either possible, or if theres a work around, like a way to save the previously entered content as the value. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use the help of cookie for save the previously entered content

Answer (score 0):

Save it in a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) and retrieve it anywhere using the key just start the session like below :

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>

<?php
// Set session variables
$content = $_POST['content']
$_SESSION["content"] = $content;

echo "Session variables are set."+ $_SESSION["content"] ;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with PHP you need to learn about [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) and [cookies](http://php.net/manual/ro/features.cookies.php).

Here is an example with cookies

```
<?php
start_session();
if(isset($_GET["title"])) {
    if(isset($_SESSION["oldTitle"])) {
        // do what you want to do
    }
    // update to the new value
    $_SESSION["oldTitle"] = $_GET["title"];
}
```